# calculate folder size or file size in jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We write our jenkins pipeline using groovy script. Is there any way to identify the folder size or file size.

Our goal is to identify size of two zip files and calculate the difference between them.

I tried below code but its not working.

```
        stage('Calculate Opatch size')
        { 
        def sampleDir = new File('${BuildPathPublishRoot}')
        def sampleDirSize = sampleDir.directorySize()
 
        echo sampleDirSize

        }
```

Getting below error :-

hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.directorySize() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: directorySize()
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:154)

Comment: You can use the [findFiles](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace) step that will find files and return an array of file info objects who's properties you can then query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. Grab all the files in a directory and sum the lengths.

*Please note that you'll need to use quotes (") in order for string interpolation to work, i.e. "${BuildPathPublishRoot}" places the value of the **BuildPathPublishRoot** variable into the string, whereas '${BuildPathPublishRoot}' is taken literally to be the directory name.*

```
workspaceSize = directorySize("${BuildPathPublishRoot}")

/** Computes bytes in the directory*/
public def directorySize(directory){
    long bytes = 0
    directory = (directory?:'').replace('\\','/')
    directory = (directory =='') ? '' : (directory.endsWith('/') ? directory : "${directory}/")
    def files=findFiles(glob: "${directory}*.*")
    for (file in files) {
        if (!file.isDirectory()){
            bytes += file.length
        }
    }
    return bytes
}
```